# Move to next line in StreamReader

Tags: vb.net, loops, streamreader, readline

Is it possible inside a loop to either move to next line or temporarily read next line?  I have not had much luck finding any useful data on how one would do this, my guess is somehow find the line number (index) of what line you are currently on and then read +1 from where you are.

```
Using TestFile As New IO.StreamReader(My.Settings.cfgPath & "tempRPT.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default, False, 4096)
        Do Until TestFile.EndOfStream
            ScriptLine = TestFile.ReadLine
            ScriptLine = LCase(ScriptLine)
            If InStr(ScriptLine, "update: [b") Then
                Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(ScriptLine, "\(([^)]*)\)")
                builder.AppendLine(m.Value)

                'This is where it would move to next line temporarily to read from it
                If InStr(ScriptLine, "hive: write:") > 0 Or InStr(ScriptLine, "update: [b") > 0 Then 'And InStr(ScriptLine, "setmarkerposlocal.sqf") < 1 Then
                   builder.AppendLine(ScriptLine)

                End If
            End If

        Loop
    End Using
```

Comment: You can read the entire file in memory with `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Real all the lines and put them in a `Queue(Of T)` object.

```
    Dim path As String = My.Settings.cfgPath & "tempRPT.txt"

    Dim lines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
    Dim que = New Queue(Of String)(lines)

    Do While que.Count > 0
        ScriptLine = que.Dequeue()
        ScriptLine = LCase(ScriptLine)
        If InStr(ScriptLine, "update: [b") Then
            Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(ScriptLine, "\(([^)]*)\)")
            builder.AppendLine(m.Value)

            Dim next_line As String = que.Peek      'Read next line temporarily                'This is where it would move to next line temporarily to read from it
            If InStr(next_line, "hive: write:") > 0 Or InStr(next_line, "update: [b") > 0 Then 'And InStr(next_line, "setmarkerposlocal.sqf") < 1 Then
                builder.AppendLine(next_line)
            End If
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: Make sure you don't `Peek` in an empty collection.

Comment: This and NoAlias' answers are both great ones.  I'm going to try this one first to see how it works. I appreciate this :)

Comment: in the end I ended up using yours.  Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not using an old version of .Net, you may find it easier to just use a list of strings.

```
Dim lstLinesInTextFile As List(of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines(My.Settings.cfgPath & "tempRPT.txt").ToList()

        Dim intCursor As Integer = 0
        For Each strLine As String In lstLinesInTextFile

            'Perform Logic Here

            'To View Next Line:
            If lstLinesInTextFile.Count > intCursor + 1 Then

                Dim strNextLine As String = lstLinesInTextFile(intCursor + 1)

                'Perform Logic Here.

            End If

            intCursor += 1

        Next
```